# Loading multiple levels of related data in Entity Framework Core not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

I want to eagerly load some data related to an `Article` object.

```
return await context.Articles
    .Include(x => x.ArticleTags)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Tag)
            // .ThenInclude(x => x.Value)
    .Include(x => x.Author)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UserInfo)
    .Include(x => x.Approver)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UserInfo)
    .Include(x => x.Rejecter)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UserInfo)
    .Include(x => x.LinkSubmitter)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UserInfo)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

In this article object, all of the displayed properties can be null or empty. `e.g. no tags, no author, no approver .. etc.`

The query works as is (with the commented out line).

However, if I include the nested `ThenInclude()`, it fails with an error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

I believe the reason for this is because the article has no tags and It's trying to eagerly load the value of tags that don't exist. How would I eagerly load all tag data which may or may not exist for the article?

Comment: From the comments looks like the `Value` property is `string`. `Include` / `ThenInclude` are used for eager loading related data, i.e. navigation properties. It cannot be used with primitive properties because they are loaded along with the corresponding entity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `.Include(x => x.ArticleTags.Tag?.Value)`

Comment: Running into the same issue

Comment: Ok, try to add ?. Updated answer

Comment: Doesn't compile for me

Comment: What type is Value of?

Comment: Value is a String

Comment: @ShermanS Also check, that `Tag` and `Value` are nullable in database